# Is there a general algorithm for these "simple" arithmetic problems?!

Tags: arithmetic

Find a number with two digits such that when it is divided with the number itself in reverse order it gives the value 1 and remainder 9, while when it is divided by the sum of its digits it gives 5 and remainder 11.

My attempt:

Write this number as $z=xy$,  from the conditions of the problem we have:
$$xy=yx+9$$ and $$xy=5x+5y+11$$ How to proceed from here?! Is there a simpler method?

Comment: It should be $\overline{xy}=\overline{yx}+9$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Observe that

$$10x+y=10y+x+9\iff x=y+1$$

$$\implies10x+y=10(y+1)+y=11y+10$$

Now $$11y+10=5\{y+(y+1)\}+11\implies y=?,x=?$$